# TextInputLayout counter and margin problem

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

When using `TextInputLayout` with height set to anything else that `wrap_content` the counter disappears, and i'd also like to use it with ConstraintLayout, with it's height set to `0dp`, with that the counter disappears and there's this margin at the top. Can the height of `TextInputLayout` be set to `0dp` with visible counter and without this margin at the top?

[image]

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:counterMaxLength="180"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#2342"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions" />


    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see what the issue is, you might have to rethink the layout design. The issue is not the TextInputLayout, it is the TextInputEditText. When you set TextInputEditText to match parent, it is matching the height TextInputLayout, hence there is no space left in the TextInputLayout to draw the counter. so if you change that height value of the TextInputEditText to any other value, you will see the counter.

My suggestion is, you either need to rethink your designed layout, or you would have to programmatically set the height of the InputEditText, depending on the activity's window visible height.

Comment: I see, I could also use normal `EditText` there and make the counter myself from two `editText`s. Which one would you recommend? Programmatically setting height like you mentioned or just making my own counter, or there's no big difference?

Comment: I will say try and set the height programmatically, with enough space to show the counter, if it proves to be difficult, then try your approach.

Answer (score 0):

I found that `TextInputLayout` inherits from `LinearLayout`. So I tried some combinations with `layout_height` and `layout_weight`. Finally, I found a solution to make `TextInputLayout` can have any kind of height and **counter** still visible.

In `TextInputEditText`, you have to set `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and `android:layout_weight="1"`

Yes, it's weird, but it works on API 30 and API 27

#### screenshot

[image: sample]

#### sample code

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Label"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:counterMaxLength="10000">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:maxLength="10000" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Checkbox" />

</LinearLayout>
```